# Casting Gtk.NodeView to another class in C#

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I am very new to Gtk# (less than a week), so hopefully this isn't a completely wrong-minded question:

I have a NodeView widget in a Gtk# window. It's simply a list of songs.  When I click on the song, I would like to update a "Currently Playing:" label.

My code so far is below:

```
protected void onSongSelected(object o, RowActivatedArgs args)
    {
        object selection = o;
        //something needs to go here
        currentSongName.Text = selection.ToString();
    }
```

Now, I know this is incorrect.  But, what this gives me is the type of the object o (and consequently the variable "selection"), which is "Gtk.NodeView".  However, I can't figure out what to do with NodeView that will let me access any information from the selected node.

I tried to remedy my problem by following the guide from this page:
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/nodeview-tutorial/

I created a TreeNode class called MasterLibrary (nearly identical to the example) and tried to cast o as type MasterLibrary like this:

```
object selection = (MasterLibrary)o;
```

However, this causes my program to crash by saying that it is invalid to cast NodeView into the MasterLibrary class.

Any help on fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NodeView's selected item can be identified using the `Selection` property. You need to use to a *TreeIter* and *TreeModel* as follows:

```
Gtk.TreeIter _i;
Gtk.TreeModel _m;
if (myNodeView.Selection.CountSelectedRows () > 0) {
  myNodeView.Selection.GetSelected (out _m, out _i);
  if (_m != null && _i != null) {
    currentSongName.text = _m.GetValue (_i, 0); // assuming your song name is in column 0 of the NodeView.
  }
}
```

Note it is best to do a check on the selected row count first to avoid null reference exceptions, but I do both that and a check for null on the model and iter based on defensive programming. If a different column (i.e. not col 0) contains your song name then simply change the column # from 0 to something else.